# Подскажите как мне передать значение одной переменной в другой модуль

Tags: python, mysql, импорт

У меня первый модуль database запрашивает номер у пользователя потом ищет его по бд когда находит сохраняет его id в переменную.
database: https://hastebin.com/odapokahif.py
Вот я и хочу сделать что бы 3 модуль принимал эту переменную и по этому id делал update этой ячейки в бд
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

`from database import res_out` (или *) => при использовании просто `res_out`

`import database` => при использовании `database.res_out`